# связанные таблицы mysql и redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Опыта и понимания ООП маловато, но задача стоит и его надо решать) расскажу суть моей задачи.
Надо создать личный кабинет где будет 3 таблицы users - клиенты, objects - объекты клиентов, requests - обращения клиентов. И тут сразу вопрос как мне связать объекты и обращения с клиентами? чтобы понимать что именно его объект и его обращение?
Сделал регистрацию и авторизацию через redbeanphp, отлично работает. И тут же в регистрации хочу добавлять объекты этих клиентов как это можно сделать?
if(empty($errors)) {

```
// Все проверено, регистрируем
// Создаем таблицу users
$user = R::dispense('users');

            // добавляем в таблицу записи
$user->login = $data['login'];
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->name = $data['name'];
$user->family = $data['family'];

// Хешируем пароль
$user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Сохраняем таблицу
R::store($user);
    echo '<div style="color: green; ">Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Можно <a href="login.php">авторизоваться</a>.</div><hr>';
```

}

После R::store($user); писать новый запрос но уже с новой таблицой?

Comment: *И тут сразу вопрос как мне связать объекты и обращения с клиентами?* Это Вы должны ответить на этот вопрос. На основании знаний о предметной области и проделанного анализа. Мы-то напридумываем... вот только потом окажется, что придуманное никак не соприкасается с реальностью... может, обращения вообще никак не связаны с объектами - и придумать такую предметную область несложно. *тут же в регистрации хочу добавлять объекты этих клиентов* Заведомая ерунда. Только не говорите, что добавление объекта - это обязательный этап регистрации. Не поверю.

Comment: @Akina нет не обязательный, можно после регистрации добавить когда зарегистрируются. Вообще клиент должен делать обращения в этих обращениях он должен указать из своих объектов которые у него есть. В итоге он должен у себя в кабинете видеть свои обращения, в них указывать какой объект. Будет еще личный кабинет диспетчера, который будет видеть все обращения всех клиентов(соответственно видеть и объекты клиента, а так же менять статус )

Comment: *нет не обязательный, можно после регистрации добавить когда зарегистрируются.* Неверно. Процессы не связаны вообще никак. За исключением того, что наличие регистрации - обязательное требование для создания объекта (наверное...).

Comment: @Akina да все верно, у меня вообще не пускает в личный кабинет если не зарегистрирован. Как правильно составить таблицу чтобы выводить обращения с тем кто именно это обращение добавил и какой именно объект он выбрал

Comment: Наверное, в таблице обращений должно быть поле - внешний ключ, которое ссылается на таблицу пользователей. При условии, что обращения всегда индивидуальны, конечно. Или на таблицу объектов, если обращение привязано к объекту, а тот в свою очередь будет ссылаться на юзера. Я ж сказал - нужен анализ предметной области.

Comment: Какое отношение код регистрации имеет к связям между таблицами? Вопрос вида "хочу стать художником, купил рамки, висят идеально. объясните что делать дальше". И при чем здесь ООП? может быть SQL имеется в виду?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561